# Replace a failed disk in EMC CX2-30 san

Tags: storage-area-network, diskmanagement, emc

Where can I find the procedure for replacing a disk in an EMC CX2-30 san.

Amber light showing on one disk, NaviSphere shows the disk status as "Requested Bypass"

The affected LUN is in a RAID 5 configuration.

There are two hot spares in the unowned LUN, one has status "Hot spare ready".  The other has status "Enabled".

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do.. I would move one of the two hotspares over to the raid5 lun so it can begin to rebuild it.. once rebuilt just remove the disk and put in a replacement.

If still under warranty EMC will send a tech out to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From EMC Powerlink you can download the Unisphere Service Manager, install this on a management station with access to the array via https.  It will have a wizard in it to guide you through the drive replacement after confirming it has moved over to hot spare/etc.

Again, if you have support on the array though, EMC will dispatch a technician to replace it for you.